# Get X days out of an Array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array filled with Datetime objects:

```
[Mon, 22 Jun 2015, Tue, 23 Jun 2015, Wed, 24 Jun 2015, Thu, 25 Jun 2015, Fri, 26 Jun 2015, Sat, 27 Jun 2015, Sun, 28 Jun 2015]
```

I know how to select what I want from the array
ex:

```
week.select{|x|x.monday? || x.wednesday?}
```

But now when I try to write a method to select days from the array, I can't seem to figure out how to pass these methods to the select statement:

ex:

```
def get_days(wkn, desired_days*)
get_week = Model.week(2)
get_days_of_week = get_week.select{|x|x.desired_day[monday]?|| x.desired_day[sunday]} 
end
```

any ideas?

desired_days would be a user saying that they want mon. and sun.
so mon, sun will get passed in as desired_days
the method will get a full week range
and then I want select out the desired days.

Comment: can you supply what you want to pass to the method and a return result? your method right now accepts 2 arguments `wkn` and `desired_days` (which should be `*desired_days`) but I don't know what these are in this context. Disregarding what `wkn` is and given `desired_days` is something like `["Monday","Friday","Saturday"]` you coudl go with `get_week.select{|x| desired_days.include?(x.strftime("%A")}

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because your array, which is supposed to contain `DateTime` objects, contains invalid Ruby objects (sequences of characters *sans* quotes).  You should also give that array a name (e.g., `arr =...`) so that answers can just refer to the array by its name, without having to define it (e.g., `arr = [#<DateTime: 2015-06-22T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457196j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<DateTime: 2015-06-23T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457197j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,...]`, where `require 'date'; arr = ["Mon, 22 Jun 2015", "Tue, 23 Jun 2015",...].map {|s| DateTime.parse(s)}`.

Comment: Normally you are right. but I plan on passing an array with the full word of desired days. So it will match when strftime('%A') does its evaluation .

Comment: @Arnold_Sanders what database are you using because we could make the database do the lifting too. While it does not seem that important now since you are selecting a single week, max of 7 days, but if you wanted to find all the Wednesdays it might make more sense to have the database handle this but this method would be db dependent where as the current suggestions are not.

Comment: @engineersmnky Im using Pg. I am currently doing a simple where statement on the desired column in order to do the query.            `db_shifts = self.where(:shift_day => favorite_days)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
def get_days(wkn, *desired_days)
  get_week = Model.week(2)
  get_days_of_week = get_week.select { |x| desired_days.include? x.strftime("%A") }
end
```

Comment: If he wants to pass words instead of integers you might want to add something like `desired_days.include?(x.strftime("%A"))`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for that suggestion. I am going to modify this post with that in the pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `wkn` is the week number and that `desired_days` is an array of day names like 'monday' or 'wednesday':

```
def get_days(wkn, desired_days)
  get_week = Model.week(wkn)
  get_days_of_week = get_week.select do |x|
    desired_days.any? { |day_name| x.send(day_name + '?') }
  end 
end
```

Comment: this will help me enormously in the future. The need for that send method keeps popping up everywhere!

Comment: While this is technically correct, and will show very limited impact when iterating over a maximum of 7 days, `include?` is still ~60% faster than converting the array to an enumerable and iterating every time not to mention the additional method calls.